# Create image of imageview having textview on it

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imageview, drawingcache

HI'm having an `imageview` having `EditText` on that Image. I want to create single Image of that `imageview` with `EditText`.

I tryed this,

```
editTextOptOneInput.buildDrawingCache();
imageViewOptOne.setImageBitmap(editTextOptOneInput.getDrawingCache());
imageViewOptOne.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap1 = imageViewOptOne.getDrawingCache();
```

but chamge my image to black as my text color is black(I guess).

Comment: Try using `myContainer.buildDrawingCache();`, instead. `myContainer` being the layout which contains both your EditText and your ImageView. Remove the other two **conflicting** `.buildDrawingCache()` **instructions**.

Comment: I'm having a relative layout with multiple `Imageview` has visibility gone. Only one `Imageview` with image, Edittext with text and another `Imageview` with delete icon is there. I don't want that delete icon in my final image, what should i do??

Comment: Sorry I don't get it..

Comment: You may use only **1** `buildDrawingCache()`, the subsequent ones will replace the previous contents. So, you better **group the EditText and the ImageView into a container** and shoot that one. OR... Instead of using an EditText, just use a **TextView**. This one can have one or more **compound** drawable **inside**. So, you may shoot the TextView only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use only **1** buildDrawingCache(), the subsequent ones will **replace** the previous contents.
So, you better **group the EditText and the ImageView into a container** and shoot that one.

OR...

Instead of using an EditText, just use a TextView.
This one can have one or more **compound drawable** inside.

So, you may shoot the TextView only.

This is a **preferred** solution, since it reduces the View and (possibly) the layout count.

**[EDIT]**

To use compound drawables simply use in xml the `android:drawableLeft = "@drawable/your_drawable"` (and/or drawableRight, drawableTop, drawableBottom) attribute/s of your TextView.
To set them in Java, use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`, as found in the official docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: can you please share some code or nay relevant link

Comment: I updated my answer to include a reference to the official docs about compound drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You need get drawing cache of **Parent** of that ***imageview*** & ***EditText***.

```
parentLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap1 = parentLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Where **parentLayout** contains ***imageview*** & ***EditText***.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need that but as I understand you should create new Bitmap object from drawing cache before set as source of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Reminder:

If you are capturing the result image+text from screen, the quality of the output image is certainly compromised

If you want to keep the original quality of image, you should use Canvas and Bitmap to help you

```
Canvas c=new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(bitmap);   // *mutable* copy of bitmap of the image for the ImageView
c.drawText(text,  x,  y,  paint);  // font size and typeface can be set through "Paint" class

bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(out)); // export output
```